# Throwing errors in Javascript with error object relevancy

Tags: javascript, error-handling, throw

This is pretty much IE related because IE is the environment I'm using to test this, but I want to know if you can affect the relevancy of the error object properties when you throw an error.  Consider the following javascript:

```
function MyClass (Arg1, Arg2)    // Line 5 of my.js
{
    if (typeof Arg1 != "string")
        throw new Error("Invalid argument passed for MyClass");
    // Do some other stuff here
}
```

Further down your code you have

```
var myvar = new MyClass(100, "Hello");    // Line 3201 of my.js
```

So the above would throw an error, but the error reported in the debugging information would show the error being thrown at line 9 of my.js instead of line 3201.  Is this something you can change using standard methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are actually looking for is a stack trace for the error.  There are no standards for this but most browsers do provide some means of discovery.  Doing a quick search comes up with this [js stack trace](http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/) example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I've looking into stack tracing without a debugger and found a pretty useful link http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/.  I build Windows Desktop Gadgets (built on IE) and rather than use Visual Studio for debugging I usually just handle window.onerror and alert with the line/error message so I can go straight to it in the code - it's quick and easy enough that way but I can see how seeing the stack could be even more useful.

Comment: Just realized your link was the same one - whoops :)

Comment: Marked this as the answer because it was the first one.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In firefox you can use the stack property when you catch the error. In other browsers you can use the message property.

Have a look at this link on how to catch the [stacktrace](http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/).

Comment: I found that link earlier and it's quite interesting, thanks.